# Understanding OpenCV cascade xml file for smile like emotion detection

Tags: ios, opencv

I am trying use OpenCV to detect smile from face on real time video on iOS project. I have some sample and trying to make it work. I have seen a cascade smile.xml file being added in the project. When I tested the app, it couldn't detect smile face coming from camera video. I doubt, how this cascade.xml file created? Is there any standard cascade xml files (to use CvHaarClassifierCascade) to detect emotions like smile, sad etc.?

I am looking at this sample here, https://github.com/lukagabric/iOS-OpenCV

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"smile" ofType:@"xml"];
    _cascade = (CvHaarClassifierCascade*)cvLoad([path cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding], NULL, NULL, NULL);
    _storage = cvCreateMemStorage(0);

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didCaptureIplImage:(IplImage *)iplImage
{
    IplImage *imgRGB = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(iplImage), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
    cvCvtColor(iplImage, imgRGB, CV_BGR2RGB);

    IplImage *imgSmall = cvCreateImage(cvSize(imgRGB->width/2, imgRGB->height/2), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
    cvPyrDown(imgRGB, imgSmall, CV_GAUSSIAN_5x5);

    CvSeq *smiles = cvHaarDetectObjects(imgSmall, _cascade, _storage, 1.1f, 3, CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING);

    for (int i = 0; i < smiles->total; i++)
    {
        CvRect cvrect = *(CvRect*)cvGetSeqElem(smiles, 0);

        Mat matImgSmall = Mat(imgSmall);

        rectangle(matImgSmall, cvrect, Scalar(255, 0, 0));
    }

    if (smiles->total > 0)
    {
        [self showSmileWithImage:imgSmall];
    }
    else
    {
        cvReleaseImage(&imgSmall);
    }

    [self didFinishProcessingImage:imgRGB];
}
```

Comment: Just passing by, please see this http://blog.dlib.net/2014/08/real-time-face-pose-estimation.html and use Face detection(Haar, LBP or HOG). Face has more unique and easy perceivable features than smile, and will also help when camera is not very focused on the smile.